# ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range" file /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring, qlist

I have recently been working on a project. When I attempt to run the project I get this error:

```
/ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h, line 487
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

How I might go about tracking down the source of the problem?

I believe that the addition of this code is causing the error

```
startvaluexy = Client::straightxy;
qDebug() << "start value Received from server :" << startvaluexy;
QStringList xy = startvaluexy.split("|");

x = xy[2];

QString num1 = x;
int x = num1.toInt();

qDebug() << "start x value :" << x;

y = xy[3];

QString num2 = y;
int y = num2.toInt();

qDebug() << "start y value :" << y;
```

When this `x = xy[2];` `y = xy[3];` is taken out, then runs fine.

Comment: Try to do this in pure shell and check if it has same behaviour or not. The code would be something like `export 13 > /sys/class/gpio/export; echo low > /sysclass/gpio/gpio13/direction; for x in $(seq 1000); do echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value; sleep 1; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine.

```
startvaluexy = EchoClient::straightxy;
qDebug() << "start xy value Received from server :" << startvaluexy;
QStringList xy = startvaluexy.split("|");
int xySize = xy.size();
qDebug() << "start xy size :" << xySize;

if(xySize < 4){
    return false;
}

bool ok;
int x = xy[2].toInt(&ok);
if(!ok){
    return false;
}

int y = xy[3].toInt(&ok);
if(!ok){
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the size of the xy list returned by split using xy.size()

... not sure what your code means,but i would write something like this

```
if(xySize >= 4){
     QString num1 = xy[2];
     QString num2 = xy[3];

     int x = num1.toInt();
     int y = num2.toInt();

     qDebug() << "start x value :" << x;
     qDebug() << "start y value :" << y;

     xstart = x;
     ystart = y;
}
```

Comment: Means you are saying like this `int xySize = xy.size();`

Comment: I have posted final code what I have tried similar, That is working fine. You can verify that.